# メール送信の方式と、OP25Bの現状について

Tags: mail

OP25B(Outbound port 25 Blocking)について、教えてください。

ある 25番ポートの制限がかかったIaaSでメールサーバーを立てようとしています。
リレーが無いとメール送信が出来ないと言われました。
ここで疑問が2つあります。

1. 587番ポートや465番ポートが使える場合は、587 -> 587 といった通信をすると思っていましたが間違っていますでしょうか？587 -> 25でしょうか？
2. OP25Bの現状は、25番ポートが使えないとメール配達がほぼ出来ない状態にも関わらず「とりあえず制限している」状態でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 587番ポートや465番ポートが使える場合は、587 -> 587 といった通信をすると思っていましたが間違っていますでしょうか？587 -> 25でしょうか？

通常、メールサーバーが別のメールサーバーにメールを送信する場合、次のようなポートが使われます。

- 送信元ポート: OSで設定されている大きめなランダムなポート(一般的なLinuxの設定では32768から60999)
- 送信先ポート: 25

OP25Bは、送信元ポートは関係無く、送信先ポートが25番である通信(例えば、45678 -> 25といったもの)を全て遮断するというものです。

OP25Bの環境でも、465番や587番への送信は可能です。ですが、一般的なメールサーバーでは次のようになっています。

- 587番はそのサーバーの利用者向けのSubmissionポートとして用意されており、サーバーがメールを受信する条件として認証が必須となっています。他のメールサーバーからメールを受信できるようにはなっていません。
- 465番はSSL/TLSなSMTP(25や587はSTARTTLSは可能だが、最初はプレーン)として設定されていますが、RFCでの扱いも二転三転しているため、全てのメールサーバーで提供されているとは限りません。また、最新のRFCでは587と同様にSubimissionとして使うべきとされているため、認証が必須になっている事があります。

465番と587番へ送信可能であると言っても、送りたい側のメールサーバーが受け付けることができないと言うことが度々発生する可能性が高いため、通常のメールサーバーのようにメールを送信できると期待することはできません。

> 2. OP25Bの現状は、25番ポートが使えないとメール配達がほぼ出来ない状態にも関わらず「とりあえず制限している」状態でしょうか？

OP25Bの制限はスパム業者に悪用されないためです。最初は乗っ取られらた一般ユーザーのパソコンがメールを送信するのを防ぐために家庭向けのプロバイダーでOP25Bが活用されていました。EC2等のIaaSが普及して、手軽にメールサーバーを立てられるようになると、今度はそれらをスパム業者が悪用するようになったため、同様にOP25Bを設定するところが増えてきたと言うことです。(サービスによっては固定IPにすることで制限が解除されたりします。)

---

単にメールを送信したいとう場合は依存のメールサービスを利用した方が無難です。メールサービスを構築したいというのであれば、OP25Bが設定されていないサービスを探すしかないです。